# FreeSWITCH dialplan to check if enduser is registered for WebRTC to SIP

Tags: webrtc, sip, freeswitch

I am trying to use [FreesSWITCH](https://freeswitch.org/) with the Mizu [WebRTC to SIP client](https://www.mizu-voip.com/Software/WebPhone.aspx).
If the called user is registered to FreesSWITCH than the call should be routed to the user. Otherwise the call should be routed to outbound SIP server.

The problem is that I am unable to find out from the FreesSWITCH dialplan if user is currently registered or not. I have the following in the default dialplan:

```
<!-- If the user doesn't exist, forward to outbound SIP -->
<extension name="check_user">
    <condition field="${user_exists(id ${destination_number} $${domain})}" expression="false">
        <action application="bridge" data="sofia/gateway/asterisk/${destination_number}"/>
    </condition>
</extension>

<!-- If the user is registered, forward the call to them -->
<extension name="check_user_registered">
    <condition field="${sofia_contact(profile/${destination_number}@$${domain})}" expression="(.+)">
        <action application="bridge" data="$1" />
    </condition>
</extension>

<!-- Otherwise forward to outbound SIP -->
<extension name="outbound">
    <condition field="destination_number" expression="^.*$">
        <action application="bridge" data="sofia/gateway/asterisk/${destination_number}"/>
    </condition>
</extension>
```

However the "check_user_registered" rule seems to be passed even if the user is not actually registered from the Webphone, so the FreesSWITCH will go to send the call to the user, but then finds out that it is not registered and the call fails. (I think that WebRTC doesn't matter here, this would be the same for SIP to SIP calls).This is the relevant log:

```
Dialplan: sofia/internal/2233@81.12.74.77 Regex (PASS) [check_user_registered] ${sofia_contact(profile/${destination_number}@rtc.mizu-voip.com)}(error/user_not_registered) =~ /(.+)/ break=on-false
Dialplan: sofia/internal/2233@81.12.74.77 Action bridge(error/user_not_registered)
Freeswitch hangup with 480 Temporarily Unavailable / USER_NOT_REGISTERED
```

Do you know any reliable way to query from FreesSWITCH dialplan the user registered status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sofia_contact` to know whether the called person is registered or not.

For example:

- `sofia_contact 1001` return this to me
  sofia/internal/sip:1001@myip_address:52573;rinstance=a1b0a9cfddc6a8c3;transport=TCP
- `sofia_contact 1002`
  error/user_not_registered

Another option is to store the registered user into database and using odbc query fetch the result and compare.(That will be a brilliant idea)

Comment: i have done it with odbc_query if you want i can do it for you.reply me

Comment: I am trying this from my "check_user_registered" rule but doesn't work as expected. Maybe you can fix that rule to not pass if user is actually not registered (now the rule is passed even if user is not registered).

Comment: finally solved with regexp as you suggested ...maybe the main problem here was my poor regexp knowledge

Answer (score 1):

`sofia_contact` returns the string `error/user_not_registered` if the user is not registered. And in your condition, you check the returned value against `.+` regular expression. Of course the error string would match too.

You need a condition which matches on `^error`, and then define the action and anti-action.

Comment: Maybe I am asking too much, but can you please modify my "check_user_registered" dialplan rule to check this error string? I am very unfamiliar with regexp.

Comment: well, you need to learn regexp to work efficiently with FreeSWITCH. There's tons of documentation and tutorials, and it's not really a complicated topic. Also I actually gave you the matching string above.